# How can I use pytest-django to create a user object only once per session?

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures, pytest-django, django-fixtures

First, I tired this:

```
@pytest.mark.django_db
@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def created_user(django_db_blocker):
    with django_db_blocker.unblock():
        return CustomUser.objects.create_user("User", "UserPassword")

def test_api_create(created_user):
    user = created_user()
    assert user is not None
```

But I got an `UndefinedTable` error. So marking my fixture with `@pytest.mark.django_db` somehow didn’t actually register my Django DB. So next I tried pass the db object directly to the fixture:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def created_user(db, django_db_blocker):
    with django_db_blocker.unblock():
        return CustomUser.objects.create_user("User", "UserPassword")

def test_api_create(created_user):
    user = created_user()
    assert user is not None
```

But then I got an error

```
ScopeMismatch: You tried to access the 'function' scoped fixture 'db' with a 'session' scoped request object, involved factories
```

So finally, just to confirm everything was working, I tried:

```
@pytest.fixture
def created_user(db, django_db_blocker):
    with django_db_blocker.unblock():
        return CustomUser.objects.create_user("User", "UserPassword")

def test_api_create(created_user):
    user = created_user()
    assert user is not None
```

This works just fine, but now my create_user function is being called every single time my function is being setup or torn down. Whats the solution here?

Comment: Use `django_db_setup` instead of the `db` fixture?

Comment: Perfect, this worked, I posted the answer below

Answer (score 8, accepted):

@hoefling had the answer, I needed to pass `django_db_setup` instead.

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def created_user(django_db_setup, django_db_blocker):
    with django_db_blocker.unblock():
        return CustomUser.objects.create_user("User", "UserPassword")
```